# What is causing this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to see anything on my screen when I try to view my HTML file that imports other ReactJS files along with a CSS. So I tried to view my code in the browser using developers tool and found this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

**This is the code:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am not able to locate the cause of the error. Please help me.

Comment: Do you try to use this code (I mean this exact code) inside your HTML file?

Comment: Please post the exact error. If "Unexpected identifier" is 'import' you need to use babel-loader with webpack

Comment: Did you use a transpiler to convert JSX syntax into valid JavaScript?